# How do I calculate angular momentum of Klein-Gordon-Fock, Dirac and Proca field?

Tags: angular-momentum, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

Just as the title suggests, what is the angular momentum operator $L=\hat{L}\psi\;$ for Klein-Gordon-Fock, Dirac and Proca fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular momentum in QFT is defined in the same way as in QM:

$
L_i= \int d^3x \, (\vec{r} \wedge \vec{P})_i= \varepsilon_{ijk} \int d^3 x \, (x^j T^{0k}-x^k T^{0j})
$

where $T^{\mu \nu}$ is the energy-momentum tensor. The only thing you have to do is just the calculation of $T^{0i}$ which can be done knowing the lagrangian.